# How to set the default dates range in TortoiseGit log dialog?

Tags: tortoisegit

How do you set the default dates range in TortoiseGit log dialog?

In the *Filtering Log Messages* of the [TortoiseGit Manual](https://tortoisegit.org/docs/tortoisegit/tgit-dug-showlog.html) it is mentioned that:

> A default limitation for From can be configured in the settings dialog
>   on the Dialogs 1 page (cf. the section called “TortoiseGit Dialog
>   Settings”).

But on TortoiseGit 2.4.0.2, in that dialog I cannot find such a possibility.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

As described in the manual (cf. https://tortoisegit.org/docs/tortoisegit/tgit-dug-settings.html#tgit-dug-settings-dialogs):

[image]

It's only possible to configure the `From` value not the `To` one.